# Where is the 'do' operator on rxjs 6?

Tags: angular, rxjs, rxjs-pipeable-operators

We are slowly updagrading from angular 4 to 5 then 6. So we upgraded rxjs. I used to do

```
Observable.of(test').do(i=>console.log(i))
```

In the new rxjs, I can't find the do operator something like:

```
of('test')
.pipe(do(i=>console.log(i)
)
```

What's the proper way ?

Comment: it's renamed `do() => tap()`

Comment: Have a [Look](https://www.academind.com/learn/javascript/rxjs-6-what-changed/)